# add action for unknown custom post type in plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a plugin where i run a function when a custom post type is published. But the name of custom post types will be unknown. I have tried following code but its not working.

```
$args = array(
'public' => true
);
$pn_post_types =  get_post_types( $args, 'names' );    

foreach ($pn_opt_post_types as $pn_opt_post_type){
    $pn_action_cpt = 'publish_'.$pn_opt_post_type;
    add_action($pn_action_cpt,'pn_notification_publish');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code , it will run when any post status changes to published

```
function post_published( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ($new_status == 'publish' ) {
        // A function to perform actions when a post status changes to publish.
    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'post_published', 10, 3 );
```